# Does the inchstr() curses-function work in python?

Tags: python, c, function, curses

I want to retrieve multiple strings in one row of my terminal right now I'm using **instr()** but that only extracts the  string in that exact position. The function that should actually do this is **inchstr()** but that doesn't seem to work in python or is it?

Comment: It should use `inwstr`, but is documented only for `instr`.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Python's curses binding does not extend the underlying curses library (much). There's more than one related curses function which python might use, depending on what you are looking at, but none read more than a single line of text:

- [`int instr(`**char** `*str);`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_instr.3x.html)
- [`int inwstr(`**wchar_t** `*wstr);`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inwstr.3x.html)
- [`int inchstr(`**chtype** `*chstr);`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inchstr.3x.html)
- [`int in_wchstr(`**cchar_t** `*wchstr);`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_in_wchstr.3x.html)

The first (`instr`) and third (`inchstr`) both read from the screen, but the latter returns *attributes* (color, underline, etc) along with the text.

Python's [`instr`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/curses.html) appears to use the former, since its documentation states

> Return a bytes object of characters, extracted from the window starting at the current cursor position, or at *y*, *x* if specified. *Attributes are **stripped** from the characters.* If *n* is specified, *`instr()`* returns a string at most *n* characters long (exclusive of the trailing *`NUL`*).

The second (`inwstr`) and fourth (`in_wchstr`) differ from the other two by allowing for reading wide-characters directly.  python actually should provide for using either set (narrow or wide character interfaces), since ncurses' wide-character interface is better suited to returning Unicode strings, but it is using the narrow interface in either case, returning a byte array (and requiring the application to puzzle out how to convert the data into a string).

Comment: So there is no way for me to read multiple characters at once?

Comment: The question says "multiple strings".  You can write a function which uses the curses interface to do this.  (Regarding **how** to do that would be in a tutorial -- off-topic).

Comment: and where can I find said tutorial?